# Angular HTTP interceptor executed for embedded ng-templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, interceptor

I have an Angular interceptor working:

```js
factory('myHttpInterceptor', function ($q, $location, $rootScope) {
// do something
return function (promise) {
    return promise.then(function (response) {
        // do something
        return response;
    }, function (response) {
        // do something
        return $q.reject(response);
    });
};
})
```

and one big html file which contains templates like `<script type="text/ng-template" id="home-template">`. Unfortunately  my HTTP interceptor intercepts not only loading HTTP requests but also loading templates (which are already loaded in html file) for controllers which are defined like `when('/', {controller:MainController, templateUrl:'home-template'})`. Is there a way how to make interceptor intercepting only HTTP requests or how to recognize whether I am loading something from server or just a template?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want to intercept template requests? or do you want to intercept everything but template requests?

Comment: intercept everything but template requests

Answer (score 23):

I ran in to this issue as well.  We were adding query strings to all our $http calls with an interceptor. It ended up breaking our templates, because when looking in $templateCache the template name with query string wasn't being found (the template was originally cached with just using it's id).

Angular $httpProvider interceptors will intercept $http module calls. These $http calls are not necessarily real HTTP GET / POST requests they can also be calls to get templates in $templateCache.  It seems like when an embedded template is being referenced, first the $http module is used (which run the interceptor first) and then the $http module will look in $templateCache to see if the template is already cached.  If $http finds out the item exists in $templateCache it will return it, if not it will attempt to make an actual HTTP request to get the template.

Our solution was to include the $templateCache module in our interceptor and manually check first if the http request exists in $templateCache.  If the request is not in $templateCache add our query string, if it is in $templateCache then simply return it.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($templateCache) {
    return {
        'request' : function(request) {
            // If the request is a get and the request url is not in $templateCache
            if(request.method === 'GET' && $templateCache.get(request.url) === undefined) {
                // Item is not in $templateCache so add our query string
                request.url = request.url + '?time=' + new Date().getTime();
            }
            return request;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: To add to this, you may not need `$templateCache` injected here. I think `request.cache` points to it so `request.cache.get(request.url)` essentially does the same thing

Comment: @ragamufin this is true, although request.cache could also be set to true to enable the default $http cache

Answer (score 0):

From what I have gathered, you are looking for a way to see if the request involved a template file or not. What you could do is look at the `url` of the request and see if it contains the path to your partials directory.

Let me know if this is what you were looking for:

```
var interceptor = ['$location', '$log', '$q', function($location, $log, $q) {
    function success(response) {
        // you can examine the url of the request here
        $log.info(response.config.url)
        return response;
    }

    function error(response) {
        if (response.status === 401) {
            $location.path('/signin');
            return $q.reject(response);
        } else {
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    }
    return function(promise) {
        return promise.then(success, error);
    }
}];

$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
```