# How to remove angular $modal cache?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

In my angular app I have multiple of `$modal` instances which are created like:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: APP_CONFIG.TPL_PATH + '/path/template.html',
        controller: 'TemplateController'//...
});
```

The problem is that after viewing these modals they are cached, and if I change them, I'm forced to clear the browsers cache. Not a problem on dev machine, but an issue, when I will provide this app to potential users.

I've found these as "solutions" so far:

```
// first one
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
    $templateCache.remove(current.templateUrl);
}); // doesn't work because $modal doesn't change state

// second one
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    $templateCache.removeAll();
}); // mess Bootstrap UI which adds default partials directly to the $templateCache

// third one
$modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/app/components/your-modal.html?bust=' + Math.random().toString(36).slice(2),
            controller: 'YourModalController'
        }); // ugly and inefficient - I have to change multiple code blocks for every modal
```

Are there any sufficient solutions? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

An extra advice I got is changing template data and putting it into .js files (i.e `<p>Data</p>` to `<p>{{data}}</p>` and `$scope.data = 'Data'` in .js). Two problems I see here. How can I be sure that the .js file isn't cached by browser? How can I add extra changes to template structure (extra variables), if it's cached (i.e to `<p>{{data}}</p><img src='{{imageUrl}}>'`)?

Comment: Are you dynamically creating the `template.html` file?

Comment: @Malkus Depends on what you mean. I have stored htmls, but use angular to bind to data and display inputs (for example) with data from server (through `$http.post`). In general modals provide access to CRUD operations.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is unclear what you are asking.  Take a look at how you are structuring your files and what you are trying to accomplish and find a more angular way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, when we speak about 'sufficient' it's the matter of taste and particular problem, but I did find this answer to be quite satisfying:

You can't delete browser's cache directly with JavaScript. This is due to security demand. And it's a bit wrong to do this - lots of smart developers know better what to store and what to delete. But there is a simple trick: using of `?keyword=hash`. Even if the pages you see would be similar, if there are different hashes for them, then browser will store two versions of the pages. Adding `?keyword=hash` in every `$model.open()` is annoying and unprofessional (DRY, KISS). Let's use angular `interceptors` then.

```
yourApp.factory('HttpInterceptor', function($templateCache, APP_CONFIG) {
  return {
    'request': function(request) {
      if (request.method === 'GET' && $templateCache.get(request.url) === undefined) {
        request.url += '?ver=' + APP_CONFIG.VERSION;
      }
      return request;
    }
  };
});
```

Put it into `$httpProvider.interceptors`:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpInterceptor');
```

Now you can specify version number (take it from your repo, for instance, or include timestamps). The version is changed - browser loads the new version of your templates. The if `$templateCache.get(request.url) === undefined` condition is used for filtering requests for precached (automatically injected maybe) content.
Interceptors idea is taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25060769/4753661 .

Answer (score 1):

## A short summary about your options provided

**The first and second options:**

```
// first one
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
    $templateCache.remove(current.templateUrl);
}); // doesn't work because $modal doesn't change state

// second one
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    $templateCache.removeAll();
}); // mess Bootstrap UI which adds default partials directly to the $templateCache
```

You defenitly do not want to be arbitrarily clearing items from `$templateCache` which seems like what your first two options where doing.  Angular would then have to reAdd views to the templateCache over and over again.

**The third option:**

```
$modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/app/components/your-modal.html?bust=' + Math.random().toString(36).slice(2),
            controller: 'YourModalController'
        }); // ugly and inefficient - I have to change multiple code blocks for every modal
```

This would actually create a memory leak because you would now have an infinite number of templates being added to the $templateCache.

## Better Solutions

***My Recommended Answer***

I would recommend renaming your `template.html` file to have unique identifiable names.

*i.e. modalTemplate_alertModal.html, modalTemplate_newEmployeeModal.html...*

Then you get to actually leverage the benefits of the `$templateCache` and improve performance.

**If you absolutely cannot rename the `template.html` files.**

In this case you can clear the specific template from the templateCache before you open the modal.

```
//Get TemplateURL
var TemplateURL = APP_CONFIG.TPL_PATH + '/path/template.html';

//Remove Cached ModalTemplate
$templateCache.remove(TemplateURL);

//Open Modal
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: TemplateURL,
        controller: 'TemplateController'//...
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like I don't quite understand. I have unique names for templates, that's right, nevertheless, if I update the template structure (correct header typo myself) the browser doesn't load the updates, only cache. So how can I use $templateCache to avoid this?
The second solution is an advanced version of the third one, provided in my question - I have to change the code before every `$modal.open()`. No memory leaks though :)

Comment: So when and where are you changing the template structure?  Are there reasons you wouldn't use angular directives to toggle the display of items for the template?

Comment: I can have a static header (i.e. _<h2>Create new entry</h2>_). And then to change it (_<h2>Create new user entry</h2>). If I had previously viewed the modal, I wouldn't get the updated header without clearing cache.

Answer (score 0):

> I can have a static header (i.e. `<h2>Create new entry</h2>`). And then to change it (_`<h2>Create new user entry</h2>`). If I had previously viewed the modal, I wouldn't get the updated header without clearing cache.

Based on this statement what you really want to be doing is using the `controller` and `$scope` to update these values.

```
<h2>{{modalHeader}}</h2>
```

Then wherever you are defining what the header needs to be update he value

```
$scope.modalHeader = "Create new user entry";
```

Keep in mind angularjs compiles and manages the `DOM` the only way to properly change `DOM` values is using `directives`.

Comment: Extremely sorry to write that, but let's face another situation: I add extra field to this modal (like age). Even if I would add extra variable `$scope.age`, I would see it in my modal, because it uses cached template.

Comment: For the record: The above suggestion of using controller and $scope totally breaks the separation of markup vs logic. Also, it doesn't solve the actual problem of the modal dialog using a cached template.

Comment: @user90766 Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: @Malkus I mean,  (1) Literals such as "Create a new user entry" belong in the Markup, not in the controller - this allows changing the view without changing the controller. (2) the main problem is that angular holds on the to template cache, bypassing it by polluting the controller doesn't solve the original issue of caching.

Answer (score 0):

add the following section to your webconfig.  You will need to clear your current browser cache manually, but going foward a page reload will work,

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
        <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
        <add name="Expires" value="0" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```