# Open brand new $modal with Angular UI.Bootstrap every time

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using AngularJS with `ui.bootstrap` and have a modal directive, which works fine.

```
myApp.directive("modalButton", ['$uibModal', function ($uibModal) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            modalUrl: '@',
            modalModel: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl: scope.modalUrl, // Here I want to use an url instead.
                    controller: 'editDeliveryCtrl as ctrl',
                    resolve: {
                        model: function () {
                            return scope.modalModel;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

And used like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" modal-model="ctrl.currentDelivery" modal-button modal-url="@Url.Action("AddDelivery", "ProvisionContract", new {provisionContractId = Model.Id})">
    <span class="fa fa-plus" area-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

When a user clicks on a button with the directive a modal is shown. However, I'm using MVC.Net and the modals I'm loading is often a form with `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` or other code-behind logic. So what I really want is to reload the template every time (make a new request to the server).

I've read question below and that may be a good answer, but what I really want is to not use templates at all. I would like `$uibModal` to load it as brand new HTML instead.

[How to remove angular $modal cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34355041/how-to-remove-angular-modal-cache)

Can I make `$uibModal` reload the template as brand new HTML each time? More like [`$.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) in jQuery?

Comment: What do you mean by *brand new HTML*? Does the html under the same URL change between requests?

Comment: Yes, the HTML is rendered by the server and I want to fetch it every time the modal opens.

Comment: how about using `resolve` to get your template and show it on the modal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All templates you load in the Angular app are stored in the [`$templateCache`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) so they will not be downloaded the next time you are referring to them.

In your case, this is not the desired behavior as the HTML contents of the same URL may change over time.

Therefore, you have to remove the cached URL from the cache before opening the modal with

```
$templateCache.remove(scope.modalUrl);
```

Also, see [How to remove angular $modal cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34355041/how-to-remove-angular-modal-cache).

---

Another idea is to override the `$templateCache`'s put method so it does not store some particular paths.

```
angular.module('yourApp').decorator('$templateCache', function($delegate) {
  var originalPut = $delegate.put;
  $delegate.put = function (templatePath, contents) {
    // specifiy conditions which would tell what paths should not be cached
    if (templatePath == '/this-should-not-be-cached.html' || templatePath.match(/some-regex/)) {
      return;
    }
    else {
      originalPut(templatePath, contents);
    }
  };
  return $delegate;
});
```

You can't just disable `$templateCache` because many libraries use it to store the templates that are shipped with them (e.g. ui-bootstrap and similar).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it works great. I've read the question you're refering to (as mentioned in post). But I figured that there should be a better solution than adding and removing the cache all the time.

Comment: Have you found it or you just suppose it exists?

Comment: I _hoped_ that it existed. I have not found it. :) Can I accept your answer, **and** flag my question as a duplicate?

Comment: Actually, I don't think it is a duplicate (that's why I have not flagg it yet). The OP there says that `$templateCache.remove` does not work for him. But, I have some other haxxxy idea. Hold on, I'll edit.

Comment: Works like a charm, and I don't even think it's a hack. This is exactly what decorators are made for.