# Angular 1 - Want to intercept only Remote server calls

Tags: angularjs

I want to intercepts only remote server calls.

I tried implementing Angular http interceptor but even it is intercepting local template call.

I got every request on console and check request made in Network Tab. It is differ in numbers.

I want reset session timeout on server call

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($rootScope) {
    return {
        'request': function(config) {
            return config;
        },
        'response': function(response) {
            return response;
        },
        'responseError': function(rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 401) {
                location.reload();
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I don't know what you want can you provide what you've done and what you are getting as input and want as output?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: I want to rest session timeout watch on server call
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($rootScope) {
        return {
          'request': function(config) {
         return config;
       },
            'response': function (response) {               
                return response;
            },
            'responseError': function (rejection) {
                if(rejection.status === 401) {
                    location.reload();
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    });

Comment: code added to question

Answer (score 0):

Able to resolve it using $templateCache

Ref - [Angular HTTP interceptor executed for embedded ng-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747705/angular-http-interceptor-executed-for-embedded-ng-templates)

Below is the code if someone needed

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $rootScope,$templateCache) {
        return {
             'request': function(config) {

                if( $templateCache.get(config.url) === undefined ){
                    console.log("Interceptor  --> "+ config.url + " -" + $templateCache);
                    $rootScope.Idle.watch();
                    console.log(new Date());
                }

              return config;
            },
            'response': function (response) {
                //Will only be called for HTTP up to 300
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            },
            'responseError': function (rejection) {
                if(rejection.status === 401) {
                    location.reload();
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    });
```